# Submit only filled fields in form php

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

I have a basic form with a lot of input text boxes to fill:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="a">
<input type="text" name="b">
...
<<input type="text" name="z">>
</form>
```

I want to pass to page2.php only filled input fields and ignore the rest.
It seems simple but i can't figure it out...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's much easier to filter out the empty fields on page2.php:

```
$_GET = array_filter($_GET);
```

That removes any empty `$_GET` array entries.

If you absolutely have to do this before submitting to page2, you'll need to use client-side javascript to loop through all form fields and remove the ones that are empty. Not ideal.

Comment: @Continental This is also the better way to do it from a system design perspective. I.e. The script that displays the form shouldn't make any assumptions about how page2 (or page5, or pageBanana) will handle the data it sends over.

Comment: My first solution to analyze the empty variables in page2, but my link will look something like this: "page2.php?a=&b=&.....z=" which is ugly. And does it make sense to sent each time to page 2 hundreds of empty variables? I dont really know java. Can you show me the code tor that? thanks

Comment: @chitoiudaniel Yes it _does_ make sense. HTML forms should send whatever fields are defined. If you don't like the ugly URL, use `method="post"` instead of GET.

Comment: I'm ok with using "post". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In page2.php

use

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
// This will extract those fields which dint have value.
}
```

Alternatively you can use jQuery / Javascript to iterate over input type text and send only those fields which have values in it.